# Учёт окружения при изъятии

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как вытащить символы между `|` - учитывая что там могут быть любые символы ?

Но так же могут попадаться `игнор1` и `игнор2` и в таком  случае текст между `|` получать не нужно.

Попробовал соорудить, но не работает как нужно:

```
\|(?!игнор1)(.*?)(?!игнор2)\|
```

Пытаюсь вытащить отсюда:

```
|рандом|
|игнор1 рандом|
|рандом игнор2||рандом игнор2||игнор1 рандом|
|рандом|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\|((?:(?!игнор1)(?!игнор2)[^|])+)\|
```

Comment: Круто! - Спасибо! Это работает. - Осталось только понять почему не работало у меня xD

Comment: Потому что я на каждом символе проверяю, а ты только по краям.

Comment: А не подскажите, почему не работает если поставить ?= вместо ?!

Comment: @Vipz, а почему по-твоему оно должно работать? о_О

Comment: Всё дело в том что не выделяется группа из из за (?:) ? Но почему тогда это работает (?!). Не понятно почему не работает, блин(